# Pig Latin, for loop, string problems

Tags: c++

When I type `ask` twice, instead of getting `askyay askyay` back i only get `ask askyay`.

When I enter `dog` twice, instead of getting `ogday ogday` I get `og dogday`.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string vowels = "aeiou";
    string new_word;
    string pig_message;
    string message;
    getline(cin, message);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <= vowels.length(); i++)
    {
        if (message[0] == vowels[i])
        {
            new_word = message + "yay ";
            cout << new_word;
        }
        else if (!message[0] == vowels[i])
        {
            pig_message = message.substr(1) + message[0] + "ay";
            cout << pig_message;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::getline()` reads an entire line, including spaces.  Personally, I like that behavior, but you have to remember to handle the spaces.  Or you can use `std::cin >> message` to read whitespace-separated words.

Answer (score 3):

Substitute the variables with the values and step through the code.The result is expected since you are not splitting the words and then appending "yay" or "ay"

```
new_word = message + "yay ";
```

will result into

```
new_word  = "ask ask" + "yay";
```

and

```
pig_message = message.substr(1) + message[0] + "ay";
```

will result into

```
pig_message  = "og dog" + "d" + "ay";
```

Comment: Im kind of confused, is that only for "dog" and "ask". Or do you mean something else. Because my goal is to turn an entire sentence into pig latin.